# Increase the horizontal space of before a line in algorithm environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, indentation, algorithmicx

I have an algorithm like the bellow code. How can I align line seven with its upper lines (please look at the uploaded picture)?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{geometry}
\newgeometry{vmargin={30mm}, hmargin={25mm,25mm}}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{academicons}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{The pseudo code of the proposed accelerated BDA}\label{Alg2}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Statex Initiate the algorithm
\State $nPop \gets$ Size of population
\For {$n = 1:nPop$}
    \State $x_{ijk}$ and $l_{ijk} \gets 0$ \: \: $\forall i,j \in \mathcal{N}; k \in \mathcal{V}$
    \State $PC \gets$ All possible combinations of manufacturers and distributors
    \While {further retailer can be possibly assigned to vehicles}
        \State Randomly select a combination of manufacturer and distributor from $PC$
        \State $i \gets$ the selected manufacturer, $j \gets$ the selected distributor and
        \Statex $k \gets$ the first available vehicle of manufacturer $i$
        \If {}
        \EndIf
    \EndWhile
\EndFor
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am getting an error when I compile [your code inside a minimal example](https://pastebin.com/raw/EsGpeL5i). Why is that?

Comment: Thanks for your attention. I have modified the minimal example so you can run it with no problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a top aligned `\parbox` and fix the interline space after it, by saving the depth of the last line.

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{geometry}
\newgeometry{vmargin={30mm}, hmargin={25mm,25mm}}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{academicons}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\SplitState}[1]{%
  \State
  \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-\ALG@thistlm}{%
    #1\par\xdef\Split@prevdepth{\the\prevdepth}%
  }\par
  \prevdepth\Split@prevdepth
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{The pseudo code of the proposed accelerated BDA}\label{Alg2}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Statex Initiate the algorithm
\State $nPop \gets$ Size of population
\For {$n = 1:nPop$}
    \State $x_{ijk}$ and $l_{ijk} \gets 0$ \: \: $\forall i,j \in \mathcal{N}; k \in \mathcal{V}$
    \State $PC \gets$ All possible combinations of manufacturers and distributors
    \While {further retailer can be possibly assigned to vehicles}
        \State Randomly select a combination of manufacturer and distributor from $PC$
        \SplitState{$i \gets$ the selected manufacturer, $j \gets$ the selected distributor and \\
               $k \gets$ the first available vehicle of manufacturer $i$}
        \If {}
        \EndIf
    \EndWhile
\EndFor
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A different solution, using the current indentation, that's stored in `\ALG@thistlm`:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{geometry}
\newgeometry{vmargin={30mm}, hmargin={25mm,25mm}}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{academicons}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Statey}{\Statex\hspace*{\ALG@thistlm}}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{The pseudo code of the proposed accelerated BDA}\label{Alg2}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\Statex Initiate the algorithm
\State $nPop \gets$ Size of population
\For {$n = 1:nPop$}
    \State $x_{ijk}$ and $l_{ijk} \gets 0$ \: \: $\forall i,j \in \mathcal{N}; k \in \mathcal{V}$
    \State $PC \gets$ All possible combinations of manufacturers and distributors
    \While {further retailer can be possibly assigned to vehicles}
        \State Randomly select a combination of manufacturer and distributor from $PC$
        \State $i \gets$ the selected manufacturer, $j \gets$ the selected distributor and
        \Statey $k \gets$ the first available vehicle of manufacturer $i$
        \If {}
        \EndIf
    \EndWhile
\EndFor
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

The output is the same.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the definition of `\brokenline` below - it sets it's argument inside a `[t]`op-aligned `\parbox` of appropriate width. `\strut`s are added to ensure that the baselines are also inline with content outside the `\parbox`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{algorithm}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\brokenline}[2][t]{\parbox[#1]{\dimexpr\linewidth-\ALG@thistlm}{\strut\raggedright #2\strut}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \caption{The pseudo code of the proposed accelerated BDA}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \Statex Initiate the algorithm
    \State $\mathit{nPop} \gets$ Size of population
    \For {$n = 1:\mathit{nPop}$}
      \State $x_{ijk}$ and $l_{ijk} \gets 0$ \: \: $\forall i,j \in \mathcal{N}; k \in \mathcal{V}$
      \State $PC \gets$ All possible combinations of manufacturers and distributors
      \While {further retailer can be possibly assigned to vehicles}
        \State \brokenline{%
          Randomly select a combination of manufacturer and distributor from $PC$}
        \State \brokenline{%
          $i \gets$ the selected manufacturer, $j \gets$ the selected distributor and
          $k \gets$ the first available vehicle of manufacturer $i$}
        \If {}
        \EndIf
      \EndWhile
    \EndFor
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```